# How to use sed to obfuscate an IPv6 address

Tags: sed, security, logs, ipv6, ip-address

I have the following sed command

```
sed -i 'test.log' -e 's/\([0-9a-fA-F]\{1,4\}\:\)\{7,7\}[0-9a-fA-F]\{1,6\}/\1\w/g'
```

The goal is to erase the last two blocks of the IPv6 address. However, this sed command doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: What is the observed behaviour with the command that you are using? I.e. what's not working and how does it not work?

Comment: @Kusalananda it does not work in that it does not change the IPv6 addresses in `test.log`. They stay the same before and after running the command. There is no error message from sed while executing this command.

Comment: You're expecting exactly 7 groups of (1-4 hex digits and a colon) before the last group of (1-6 hex digits). But are the addresses in the log all in this format? If the double-colon `::` syntax is used, one or more of those groups might be entirely omitted.

Comment: Does "erase" mean eliminate entirely, or remove fields' contents but leave colons in place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how far would

```
sed -r 's/(([[:xdigit:]]{,4}:)*)[[:xdigit:]]{,4}:[[:xdigit:]]{,4}$/\1:/' file
```

get you?

Comment: this works pretty good! It only fails with adresses what have two colons before the last digit, e.g `2b01:4b8:160:80e1::2`

Comment: I find it working perfectly. What exactly do you complain about?

Comment: It does work perfectly. I failed to mention that the IPv6 address is in the first column of the file so I had to remove the `$`, my bad. Thank you very much!